# Creation of FOREGROUND SERVICE on NET MAUI to scan wifi networks

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm a new mobile app developer with Net Maui. My aim is to create a FOREGROUND SERVICE that:

scans nearby WiFi networks and saves the results in a list.

the method for scanning wifi networks must continue to work as long as the service remains active, it must scan every 10 seconds and update the list.

a notification must appear on the device indicating that the service is active and working.

the service must be started via an event in the MainPage.xaml.cs.

Still in MainPage.xaml.cs you need to view the results of the real-time scan in a listView.

I tried to create a service, implementing the method that scans wifi networks. I also check that in the list of networks found there is a network with ssid = "AndroidWifi". I have implemented an interface to start the service via an event. My problem is that when the app is closed the service remains active, but the method for scanning the networks does not work, while when the app is running everything works fine.`

```js
    [Service(ForegroundServiceType = Android.Content.PM.ForegroundService.TypeDataSync)]
    public class DemoServices : Service, IServicesTest
    {
        // private WifiManager wifiManager;
        private bool isScanning = false;      
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
            {
                var database = new Database();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è iniziato");               
                 Task.Delay(2000);

                if (!isScanning)
                {
                    isScanning = true;

                    // Esegui la scansione WiFi
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        while (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE" && isScanning == true)
                        {                                                   
                           
                            
                            var scanResults = await ScanWifiNetworks();
                                // Puoi fare qualcosa con i risultati della scansione qui
                                bool found = false;
                                foreach (var network in scanResults)
                                {
#pragma warning disable CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
                                    if (network.Ssid == "AndroidWifi")
                                    {
                                        //await DisplayAlert("Trovato!!", $"SSID '{network.Ssid}' trovato!", "OK");
                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
#pragma warning restore CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
                                }
                                if (found)
                                {
                                    MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                                    {
                                        Data = DateTime.Now,
                                        Descrizione = "Entrato"
                                    };
                                    int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                                    {
                                        Data = DateTime.Now,
                                        //Time = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(new DateTime()),
                                        Descrizione = "Uscito"
                                    };
                                    int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                                }
                                // Attendi prima di eseguire una nuova scansione
                                await Task.Delay(8000);     
                        }
                    });
                    RegisterNotification();
                }
            }
            else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è fermato");
                StopForeground(true);
                StopSelfResult(startId);
            }
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }
        public async Task<IList<ScanResult>> ScanWifiNetworks()
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.Android)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Questa funzionalità è supportata solo su dispositivi Android.");

            var scanResults = new List<ScanResult>();
            //ottengo il riferimento al servizio WifiManager
            var wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

            if (!wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
            {
                // Assicurati che il WiFi sia abilitato sul dispositivo
                wifiManager.SetWifiEnabled(true);
                await Task.Delay(2000); // Attendere un po' per accendere il WiFi
            }

            var wifiScanReceiver = new WifiScanReceiver(wifiManager);
            Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));

            // Esegui la scansione delle reti WiFi
#pragma warning disable CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma
            wifiManager.StartScan();
#pragma warning restore CA1422 // Convalida compatibilità della piattaforma

            await Task.Delay(5000); // Attendere qualche secondo per completare la scansione

            scanResults.AddRange(wifiScanReceiver.ScanResults);
            Android.App.Application.Context.UnregisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver);

            return scanResults;
        }

        class WifiScanReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            private readonly WifiManager wifiManager;

            public IList<ScanResult> ScanResults { get; private set; }

            public WifiScanReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager)
            {
                this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
                ScanResults = new List<ScanResult>();
            }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.Action == WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction)
                {
                    // Ricevi i risultati della scansione WiFi
                    var results = wifiManager.ScanResults;
                    ScanResults.Clear();

                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        // Salva l'oggetto ScanResult nella lista
                        ScanResults.Add(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(DemoServices));
            startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
            MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
        }
        public void Stop()
        {    
            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
            stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
            MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);
        }
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            //wifiManager = null;
        }

        private void RegisterNotification()
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServicioChannel", "Demo de servicio", NotificationImportance.Max);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServicioChannel")
                .SetContentTitle("Servizo Attivo")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();
            StartForeground(100, notification);
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: `My problem is that when the app is closed the service remains active, but My problem is that when the app is closed the service remains active, but the method for scanning the networks does not work` Do you mean that the service is still active, right? Then   why not put this method of scanning the networks inside the service?

Comment: show me what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done.

It is not allowed in android. You cannot use excessive Wi-Fi scanning in the background.

Modern Android versions do not allow such repeated scans.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan

With your once per 10 sec scans, you are designing nothing more than a battery melting app.

There are other ways for making your android application connect to networks.
(Suggestions, etc..)

Unless you plan to distribute this application internally, and use workarounds like custom made Devices/OS, developer mode, old versions, etc. But even then you will have to face the drawbacks of constant CPU usage and power drain.

I do not like all the restrictions Android has. But this restriction in particular is there for a very very good reason.

Comment: the app I'm creating is to be used internally. Alternatively, what other method can you recommend?

Comment: @peppeloria  If you have the devices, you can put them dev mode and disable the wifi scan throttling, and continue with your battery melting crusade. You are not telling me your business requirements, you are not telling me why you want it. You asked 4 times the same question: "how to do 360 wifi scans per hour in android?". Why do you need 10 sec reaction time without user input? And again, are we talking about swapping Wi-Fi, or just reconnecting? Android can reconnect to a network it has been connected to. Why is this not working for you?

Comment: the purpose of the app is to detect a specific wifi network, not to connect to it, if this network is detected it must perform certain operations, for this I need a constant scan of the networks.

Comment: @peppeloria Ok, if you say that the very purpose of those devices will be to scan 360 times a hour, Dev mode > wifi_scan_throttle_enabled 0 and go scan. (Next step is rooting them).